# Two loops in one python script

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python and am trying to insert a double loop in a script that is not mine.

The original script reads a .cat file (from the Spanish cadastre) and transforms it into csv through a structure in this file https://github.com/GuillemHerrera/cat2csv/blob/master/catstruct.py

The loop for phase 1 (create the csv file with structure headers) works. The loop for step 2 (read the .cat file and transform it into csv) does not work, as it only transforms the last file in the list. Any help?

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import os
from catstruct_14 import catstruct # define la estructura de un .CAT

# Reading folder for .cat files
carpeta_cat= r"C:\Users\ruben\Desktop\Alfanum\CAT"

# Writing folder for .csv files
carpeta_csv= r"C:\Users\ruben\Desktop\Alfanum\CSV"

# Iterate directory
res = [] # list to store files
for file in os.listdir(carpeta_cat):
    # check if current file_path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(carpeta_cat, file)):
        # add filename to list
        res.append(file)
        for i in res:
            rf = open(os.path.join(carpeta_cat, i), encoding='latin-1') # input file
            wf = {} # output files
        print (rf)

# Phase 1
for i in res:
    for tipo in catstruct:
        outname = os.path.splitext(i)[0]+'_cat'+str(tipo)+'.csv'
        print ('Creando ' + outname)
        wf[tipo] = open(carpeta_csv+"//"+outname, 'w')
        # Escribimos primer registro con nombres de campos
        csv.writer(wf[tipo]).writerow(i[3]for i in catstruct[tipo])

    
# Phase 2
for f in rf:
    for line in rf.readlines():
        line = (line.encode('utf-8-sig')).decode('utf-8-sig')
        row = []
        tipo = int(line[0:2])
        # Parseamos si conocemos la estructura del tipo de registro
        if tipo in catstruct:
            for campos in catstruct[tipo]:
                ini = campos[0]-1 # offset
                fin = ini + campos[1] # longitud
                valor = (line[ini:fin].strip().encode("utf-8-sig")).decode('utf-8-sig') # valor
                row.append(valor)
            csv.writer(wf[tipo]).writerow(row) 
            
            
# close input file handle
for f in rf:
    rf[f].close()  


# close output file handles
for f in wf:
    wf[f].close()
```

Comment: You iterate over input files (and multiple times over `res` - unnecessarily) and at the end `rf` is the file handler for the last file. Reconsider your logic in that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rf` is a variable, so each time open a new file you call
`rf = open(os.path.join(carpeta_cat, i), encoding='latin-1')`
and overwrite `rf`.

you could replace this with:

```
###initialise rf
rf = []
```

and then

```
###add file to rf
rf.append(open(os.path.join(carpeta_cat, i), encoding='latin-1'))
```

looks like you are already trying to iterate through `rf`:
`for f in rf:`

also, you don't want to be running this:

```
for i in res:
    rf.append(open(os.path.join(carpeta_cat, i), encoding='latin-1')) # input file
    wf = {} # output files
```

each time that you find a new file, as you will get repeated values in rf, so you should bring that out of the parent for loop.